# Concatenate multiple input sources into a single IO object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io

I have a collection of input sources -- strings, files, etc. -- that I want to concatenate and pass to an API that expects to read from a single `IO` object. The files can be quite large (~10 GB), so reading them into memory and concatenating them into a single string isn't an option. (I also considered using `IO.pipe`, but spinning up extra threads or processes seems like overkill.)

Is there an existing library class for this in Ruby, cf. Java's [`SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html)? If not, is there some other way to do it straightforwardly and idiomatically?

Comment: Are your input sources also `IO` objects?

Comment: They either are (`File`) or can be converted to be (e.g. `String` -> `StringIO`).

Comment: You could create an IO-compatible class that reads from an array of sources and works like that stream you're familiar with. When the first one hits EOF, move on to the next.

Comment: @tadman That's where I'm going if I don't get a good answer to this question. I'm hoping to find that someone's already done it.

Comment: If a thorough search of Rubygems turns up nothing, maybe this is a gem waiting to happen?

Comment: [`ARGF`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/ARGF.html) works that way, but it only operates on files (i.e. filenames, not `File` objects).

Comment: This might be relevant: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/5265536 I wrote it awhile back. It turns a series of Enumerables into a single Enumerable, so it'll do the trick if your API reads the files using Enumerable methods (`each`, `next`, etc.), but not if it uses `gets` or other IO methods that aren't from Enumerable.

Comment: Unfortunately it's writing to a socket with `IO.copy_stream`, but thanks.

Comment: @Stefan The idea of writing all the non-files to files and stuffing their names into `ARGV` for `ARGF` to read is demented, but tempting.

Comment: Can you provide the IO class methods that you need to be supported for the API to work?

Comment: @Fravadona It's been six years, I'm afraid I don't remember the specific use case.

Comment: @DavidMoles sorry. I didn't check who was the one who set the bounty, I thought it was you.

Comment: @Fravadona NP, for a second I thought it was me who set it, and I was like "how has that not expired?"

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately it's writing to a socket with `IO.copy_stream`

For `IO::copy_stream(src, ...)` to work, the **« *IO-like object for `src` should have `readpartial` or `read` method »***

So, let's try to create a class that can `read` over a sequence of IO objects; here's the spec of [`IO#read`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/IO.html#method-i-read):

> **read(maxlen = nil) → string or nil**
>
> **read(maxlen = nil, out_string) → out_string or nil**
>
> Reads bytes from the stream (in binary mode):
>
> - If `maxlen` is `nil`, reads all bytes.
> - Otherwise reads `maxlen` bytes, if available.
> - Otherwise reads all bytes.
>
> Returns a string (either a new string or the given `out_string`) containing the bytes read. The encoding of the string depends on both `maxLen` and `out_string`:
>
> - `maxlen` is `nil`: uses internal encoding of self (regardless of whether out_string was given).
> - `maxlen` not `nil`:
>
>   - `out_string` given: encoding of `out_string` not modified.
>   - `out_string` not given: **ASCII-8BIT** is used.

```rb
class ConcatIO

  def initialize(*io)
    @array = io
    @index = 0
  end

  def read(maxlen = nil, out_string = (maxlen.nil? ? "" : String.new))
    out_string.clear
    if maxlen.nil?
      if @index < @array.count
        @array[@index..-1].each{|io| out_string.concat(io.read)}
        @index = @array.count
      end
    elsif maxlen >= 0
      while out_string.bytesize < maxlen && @index < @array.count
        bytes = @array[@index].read(maxlen - out_string.bytesize)
        if bytes.nil?
          @index += 1
        else
          out_string.concat(bytes)
        end
      end
      return nil unless out_string.bytesize
    end
    out_string
  end

end
```

<sup>**note:** The code is inaccurate in regard to the encoding part of the spec.</sup>

Now let's use this class with `IO::copy_stream`:

```rb
require 'stringio'

io1 = StringIO.new(  "1")
io2 = StringIO.new( "22")
io3 = StringIO.new("333")
ioN = StringIO.new( "\n")

catio = ConcatIO.new(io1,io2,io3,ioN)

print catio.read(2), "\n"
IO.copy_stream(catio,STDOUT)
```

And it works!

```
12
2333
```

---

###### Aside

In fact there's a [multi_io](https://github.com/agis/multi_io) gem for  concatenating multiple IO sources into a single IO object; the problem is that its methods don't follow the specs of the `IO` class; for ex. you can't use it with `IO::copy_stream`, it doesn't work.

Additionally, even if you're able to use `ARGF` (ie. you're only handling input files stored in `ARGV`), you still have to be cautious: there are slight differences between some of `ARGF`'s and `IO`'s methods, so it's not 100% safe to feed `ARGF` to an API that needs to read from an IO object.

---

###### Conclusion

Because there's no gem nor core class for it, the only sensible work-around would be to determine the IO methods that the API requires and write a class that implements them. It isn't so straining, as long as you don't have to implement the whole IO interface. Furthermore, you already have a working `read` method in my answer .

Comment: The premise of the question was to get an `IO` object that combines multiple `IO` objects. The idea is that you pass it to code you have no control over (ex a gem). So you can't loop over the objects and call `IO.copy_stream` on each as the code that does `IO.copy_stream` is inside the gem. And you can't just implement `read` and `readpartial` as the gem's internal implementation might change in the future and call `sysread` instead (for example). You have to return a full blown `IO` at the end.

Comment: @ndnenkov my bad, I didn't recheck the question and focused on the comment; I removed my remark about not using a class. That said, the API can change, as well as the IO class!! So, implementing the minimal requirements for the API to work (when there's no gem for it) is a sensible solution IMHO. BTW, providing a full implementation of the IO class would go beyond the boundaries of a SO answer.

Comment: The API might change, but that should be reflected by the versioning or the changelog. I expected that there was something in the standard library/gem/or clever thingy I've missed, hence why I added the bounty. I didn't expect someone to implement the entire `IO` interface in an answer. I also saw the `multi_io` gem previously, but its `read` method reads from all sources at the same time, rather than sequence one after the other.

Comment: @ndnenkov I would say that even `ARGF` might cause problems when used with an API that needs an IO object; for example the `seek` and `close` methods only apply to the current file and not to the logical concatenation of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using StringIO to concatenate multiple input sources and pass them to an API that expects to read from a single IO object

```
require 'stringio'

# Create a new StringIO object from the first input source
input1 = StringIO.new("First input source")

# Create a new StringIO object from the second input source
input2 = StringIO.new("Second input source")

# Concatenate the two input sources into a single IO object
inputs = input1 + input2

# Pass the concatenated input sources to the API
api.process(inputs)
```

Comment: As per the question: "The files can be quite large (~10 GB), so reading them into memory and concatenating them into a single string isn't an option."